# Disable mouse changing aspect ratio in Gimp 2.10.8

Tags: gimp

I use Ctrl-Shift with the mouse wheel a lot to move left right while also clicking a straight line.  It also defaults to changing the aspect ratio of the brush which I almost never use.

How can I disable the mouse shortcut for aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to *Edit>Preferences>Input devices>Input controllers*
- Double click `Main mouse wheel` in the *Active controllers* list in the right panel
- Find your events in the list (`tools-aspect-increase`, `tools-aspect-decrease`), select them and click "Clear event".